# extract data into object from service data

Tags: angular

Guys, I have to extract data from my response on another object to use it to filter data but I find every moment

> Cannot set property 'FullName' of undefined

then how can I do it?

My model:

```
  export interface ExportArray {
    FullName: string;
    DepartmentName
    DriverName
    CurrentCarType
    CurrentCarModelString
    CurrentModelYear
    CurrentFuelTypeEnum
    FuelContainerCapacity
    MileageFloat
  }
```

My component:

```
    let prepare: ExportArray[] =[];
    let index = 0;
    this.Listtrackigobjct.forEach(e=>{
prepare[index].FullName = e.FullName;
      prepare[index].DepartmentName = e.FullName;
      prepare[index].DriverName = e.DriverName;
      prepare[index].CurrentCarType = e.CurrentCarType;
      prepare[index].CurrentCarModelString = e.CurrentCarModelString;
      prepare[index].CurrentModelYear = e.CurrentModelYear;
      prepare[index].CurrentFuelTypeEnum = e.CurrentFuelTypeEnum;
      prepare[index].FuelContainerCapacity = e.FuelContainerCapacity;
      prepare[index].MileageFloat = e.MileageFloat;
      index ++;    
      });
    console.log(prepare);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, you haven't initialized the object. You are directly accessing the array element via index, but there is no such element inside the array.

You can do the following -

```
this.Listtrackigobjct.forEach(e=>{
      // This is the initialization step
      const tempObj = {} as ExportArray;

      tempObj.FullName = e.FullName;
      tempObj.DepartmentName = e.FullName;
      .....
      .....
      prepare.push(tempObj);
      });
```

No need of index variable here. Push will insert the new object at the end of the array.